# Eventsource behind a load balanced multi instance cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I wrote a simple Web application to print the [http request via Eventsource](https://github.com/unee-t/showhook). However I realized then when deployed in a typical ECS cluster, i.e. upon **at least two** instances behind a load balancer, if the user is connected to one instance and the hook is received by the other instance (assuming load balancer dispatches two different instances), the request will not be shown.

I've seen this sort of problem before fitting other (stateful?) applications into this AWS scaling style of deployment of spinning new instances behind a load balancer. Is there a name for it? Any suggestions how to fix my program so that it can fit the AWS model? I guess the hook would need to be written to some datastore and the eventsource publisher needs to poll or rather preferably event from it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## EventSource SSE behind a Load Balanced Multi-instance Cluster

> Pull request: https://github.com/unee-t/showhook/pull/1

The servers behind the load balancer need to be kept informed of `/events`. When the event is received on the neighboring server, that server must inform the group of the received event.

[image: EventSource Golang Server]

### Example Usage

Get the repository.

```
git clone git@github.com:stephenlb/showhook.git
cd showhook
```

You have to setup the project with `make`.

```
make build
make network
```

Now you can run your containers.  Note that we have a 12MB container with your binary.  We made the container small by creating a build-container and a runtime-container in the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/stephenlb/showhook/blob/master/Dockerfile).  This takes the container from 400MB down to 12MB.

```
PORT=9000 NEIGHBORS=192.168.0.1:9001 make start
PORT=9001 NEIGHBORS=192.168.0.1:9000 make start
```

Now open your browser to load the html file.

1. http://0.0.0.0:9000
2. http://0.0.0.0:9001

Click the `/hook` link on the page in a third tab.  Notice that your first two tabs will receive the EventSource notification.

### Updated `main.go` App Server

Add an HTTP call to your neighbors on `/hook-neighbor` event handler.  You can add code to your existing Go code which notifies neighboring servers to become aware of the event.  This will allow any client to receive the event regardless of the server subscribed on the `EventSource('/events')`.

### Dynamically adding new Event Servers

When you need to scale up and down, you'll want to add/remove servers.  An easy way to keep your servers informed on new neighbors is by using service discovery.  You may consider adding **Service Discovery** such as [etcd](https://coreos.com/etcd/) and [consul](https://www.consul.io/).

You have a great start!  I built the [PubNub Network](https://www.pubnub.com/products/global-data-stream-network/) with a similar approach.

Comment: Thanks! I gave some feedback here https://github.com/unee-t/showhook/pull/1#issuecomment-391580790 since I am thinking [AWS SQS long polling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-long-polling.html) is a better approach. I am not a fan of service discovery based solutions, since I feel it's way more error prone.

Comment: Yes this should work nicely as well! Note that you will have a limit of 100 SQS Topics by default. You can ask for more. SQS is great for queuing work and tasks to be processed. 

Broadcasting updates with SQS is possible and it wasn't built for it. SQS is ideal for queuing long-running tasks that need processing time across many EC2 servers. It can be used as a delivery queue for end-target clients as long as you only have 100 target clients.

Answer (score 0):

My personal opinion is that you should find a key piece of technology (Push notifications, PubNub, Aws IOT, [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client)) to helps you solve this problem instead of building your own.

These HTTP instances are stateful and so you need to be able to share state between them. 
Scaling persistent connections is difficult and it becomes even harder with a round-robin load balancer in front of it. 
I suggest you look for a service that does all of this for you.

If you want roll your own i would suggest you look into:

- [Redis](https://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush). Using one queue per user.
- Rabbit MQ - Creating a queue per user. I don't think this will scale but maybe it works for your case.
- Use some sort sort fo clustering framework. I have no idea about GO. Platforms like Erlang/Elixir or [Akka](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.5/scala/distributed-pub-sub.html) have support for clustering. Typically you can connect to any of the nodes of the cluster and the messages will be delivered to you.

These realtime systems don't scale well using a request/response/polling model. If you don't need it to scale just store your data in mysql or REDIS and poll it.

Answer (score 0):

### SNS + SQS Fanout

In my view, this is a problem that can be neatly solved using **SNS** + **SQS**, with the **Fanout** pattern. You can architect this by having a **SNS Topic** where one service would publish a specific message (not caring about consumers at all - this helps decoupling) and you would have queues subscribed to this topic where other services would be able to consume it, in their own pace, the same messages. So, yes, this would solve the many receivers (or subscribers) problem.

[image: SNS + SQS Fanout]

It would be something like this:

> You have a topic (**TopicX**) on SNS
>
> **Service B** has its own queue (**QueueB**); **QueueB** is subscribed to **TopicX**
>
> **Service C** has its own queue (**QueueC**); **QueueC** is subscribed to **TopicX**
>
> **Service A** performs an operation that needs to be shared across your network
>
> **Service A** publishes **Message1** to **TopicX**
>
> **QueueB** receives **Message1**
>
> **QueueC** receives **Message1**
>
> **ServiceB** consumes **Message1**
>
> **ServiceB** deletes **Message1** from **QueueB**
>
> **ServiceC** consumes **Message1**
>
> **ServiceC** deletes **Message1** from **QueueC**

Check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNS_Scenarios.html for more details on this pattern.